# Error out when click Google Chat Bot interactive button

Tags: google-hangouts

I wrote up a simple bot which does nothing but an interactive button. I tested using the console, and I am able to see the message in the chat room. However, when I click the button, it spin for a while and then show the error message 'Unable to contact. Try again later.'

I am expecting the CARD_CLICKED event to be trapped by the console log statement. However, there is no such entry in the log. Is there anything I missed in the configuration?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url = [CHAT_ROOM_WEBHOOK];

function createCard() {
    return {
        'cards': [{
            'sections': [{
                'widgets': [{
                    'buttons': [{
                        'textButton': {
                            'text': 'Grab it',
                            'onClick': {
                                'action': {
                                    'actionMethodName': 'snooze'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    };
}

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.main = (req, res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    const card = createCard(req.body);
    axios
        .post(url, card)
        .then(response => {
            res.status(200).send(card);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        });
};
```

There is no handling of the interactive events in the code yet as I won't even be able to capture it.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive buttons won't work in cards that were posted by an incoming webhook, only those posted by bots. So send the `CARD_CLICKED` event it needs to know the endpoint of your service, which doesn't need to be registered with an incoming webhook.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct. I couldn't find a good example from the official doc, but I believe there is no reason I can't create a bot that is both incoming and outgoing, can I?